# Dagger2: wildcard with Generics

Tags: dagger-2

I'm new to Dagger2 and DI in general, but I'm interested to populate a map with injected keys/values. The problem is that it works if I provide the exact types, I can't make it work with wildcards, any solution for that?

```
@Module
public class SimpleIssueModule
{
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @IntoMap
  @StringKey("simple_issue")
  public SimpleIssue provideSimpleIssue()
  {
    return new SimpleIssue();
  }
}

@Module
public class DaggerFactoryModule
{
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public Factory provideFactory(Map<String, Provider< ? extends Issue>> map)
  {
    return new Factory(map);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a map of `Provider< ? extends Issue>> map`, then you need to use `Issue` as the type returned in your module. Dagger will not do any casting or guessing on its own.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@IntoMap
@StringKey("simple_issue")
public Issue provideSimpleIssue() {
  return new SimpleIssue();
}
```

> what to do in case I need a Module that provides a base class (Issue) into a Map and also need a provider of the concrete class (SimpleIssue) and I would like it to be Singleton (same instance returns in both cases)

In this case you provide the `@Singleton` of `SimpleIssue`.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public SimpleIssue provideSimpleIssue() {
  return new SimpleIssue();
}

// or you can use constructor injection, dropping the method above...

@Singleton
public class SimpleIssue {

  @Inject
  public SimpleIssue(...) {
  }
}
```

Then you bind this instance into a Map. There is no need for a scope, since the implementation should declare it (as done above).

```
@Provides
@IntoMap
@StringKey("simple_issue")
public Issue provideSimpleIssue(SimpleIssue issue) {
  return issue;
}

// or alternatively with `@Binds` when using an abstract class / interface
// this leads to actually better performing dagger code

@Binds
@IntoMap
@StringKey("simple_issue")
public Issue provideSimpleIssue(SimpleIssue issue);
```

Comment: so what to do in case I need a Module that provides a base class (Issue) into a Map and also need a provider of the concrete class (SimpleIssue) and I would like it to be Singleton (same instance returns in both cases)?

Comment: @Shvalb Have a look ;)

Comment: WOW - that looks great!, let my brain process this code and be back to you a bit later..many thanks!

Comment: one question, if I use the @Binds annotation it forces the Module class to be abstract, so how can I instantiate it when preparing the Component ?

Comment: @Shvalb even better, your module can be an interface. You don't have to add modules to the component builder when they don't require any constructor arguments, so you don't have to instantiate them. If you need arguments, you can use multiple modules, one an interface, one a normal class

Comment: Sounds Good!
You really helped me !!